# Issue with POST call to WCF service - 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: c#, ajax, json, wcf, post

I published on my Windows Server a WCF Service on IIS 7.5

It has basically two methods, just for the smoke test .

Here the ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFSMServiceWeb
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string registraUtenteViaMail(string username, string password, string key, string dbVersion);


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string loginUtenteViaMail(string username, string password, string key, string dbVersion);
}
```

and here the implementation:

```
public class FSMServiceWeb : IFSMServiceWeb
{

    public string registraUtenteViaMail(string username, string password, string key, string dbVersion)
    {
        return username + password + key + dbVersion;
    }

    public string loginUtenteViaMail(string username, string password, string key, string dbVersion)
    {
        return username + password + key + dbVersion;
    }
}
```

I have no problem to call the method call loginUtenteViaMail with GET, **but I cannot call method registraUtenteViaMail with POST method**.

Here javascript code used to test POST method

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#send").click(function(){

    var username =  $("#username").val();
    var password =  $("#password").val();
    var key =       $("#key").val();
    var dbVersion = $("#dbVersion").val();
    var dati = {username : username, password : password, key : key, dbVersion : dbVersion};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/FSMServiceWeb.svc/registraUtenteViaMail',
        data: JSON.stringify(dati),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);},
            error: function (data){},
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });
});
});
```

I obtain this error (Chrome Console):

```
POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/FSMServiceWeb.svc/registraUtenteViaMail 400 (Bad Request)                         jquery.min.js:4 
l.cors.a.crossDomain.send     jquery.min.js:4 
o.extend.ajax                 POSTtest.js:12 
(anonymous function)         jquery.min.js:3 
o.event.dispatch             jquery.min.js:3 
r.handle                     jquery.min.js:3
```

Where am I wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please post output of JSON.stringify(dati)?

Comment: console.log (JSON.stringify(dati));
returns me this:
{"username":"name","password":"secret","key":"1234","dbVersion":"1.0"}

Answer (score 3):

No way! I figured out the problem.
I miss an important part of my AJAX request:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

In fact correct request should be this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#send").click(function(){

var username =  $("#username").val();
var password =  $("#password").val();
var key =       $("#key").val();
var dbVersion = $("#dbVersion").val();
var dati = {username : username, password : password, key : key, dbVersion : dbVersion};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/FSMServiceWeb.svc/registraUtenteViaMail',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  // MISSING PART!
    data: JSON.stringify(dati),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);},
        error: function (data){},
    dataType: 'JSON'
});
});
});
```

Comment: I still have the issue despite the contentType attribute